# Can SPACE, instead of ENTER, be used to take input in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, c++14

I am writing a very simple C++ program for operator overloading and I got stuck at a problem. I want to use space to take input instead of enter. I basically want to input a complex number using operator >> but the problem is that before taking the input of the imaginary part i am printing ")+i(" but on pressing enter, the cursor shifts to next line in the terminal. How do I avoid that ?
This is what the input is doing.

```
istream &operator>>(istream &i, Complex &num){
    cout << "(";
    i>>num.a;
    cout << ")+i(";
    i>>num.b;
    cout << ")" << endl;
    return i;
}
```

This is what the input is looking like.

```
(-1
)+i(5
)
```

This is what I want the input to look like.

```
(-1)+i(5)
```

Comment: Not doable in standard C++. You may find some luck delving into platform-specific libraries that alter the bhaviour of the console, but this is usually not worth the effort.

Comment: Please don't mix input and output in the same operator. What happens if the input stream isn't even `std::cin`? If you want a specific format for the actual input, then code it into the operator. If you want to mix input and output like you do, then don't use the input operator, but rather a specialized function for it. And use OS-specific functionality to read characters directly instead of using `std::cin` (or other C++ input stream).

Comment: Note the existence of [`istream` `operator<<` for `std::complex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/operator_ltltgtgt)

Comment: You need to change the input to unbuffered.  It isn't that hard.  But it does matter what OS you use because it is platform specific.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why information is given to `std::cin` only after enter is because the standard input is buffered by default. Making it unbuffered give you control on when to instantly process or when to buffer input.

This is platform dependent but in *nix systems run:

> $ stty raw && stty echo

This makes input (and output) unbuffered while preserving echo (so you can see your input).

When reading in integers, the program will now respond instantly with any separator.

Example:

```
int main() {
  while (std::cin) {
    int a, b;
    std::cout << "( ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << ") +i ( ";
    std::cin >> b;
    std::cout << ")= " << a << " + " << b << 'i' << "\r\n";
    // Note that we need to return cursor to leftmost ^ position
  }
}
```

Run:

> g++ test.cpp && stty raw && stty echo && ./a.out

Output (input = "1 2 3 4 5 6 ":)

```
( 1 ) + i( 2 ) = 1 + 2i
( 3 ) + i( 4 ) = 3 + 4i
( 5 ) + i( 6 ) = 5 + 6i
( |
```